# can't get GUI to start from command prompt

Tags: boot, nvidia, gui

I've been running Ubuntu for some time. Last night I installed the updates that automatically download periodically and shut down. This morning the machine will only boot to the command prompt. I've tried all the "fixes" I can find on-line without success. The startx command brings up a message "API mismatch: the NVIDIA kernel module has version 304.88 but this NVIDIA driver component has version 173.14.35."..
How do I make sure both are the same? What else can I do to get this machine to boot the GUI again?

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling your drivers will solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank-you! I didn't see the purge and install suggestion in any of the threads I had looked at. That worked. GUI up and running.

Answer (score -1):

I've run into this and had to install the Nvidia driver from the command line.

If Ubuntu installed your nvidia package for you then I would suggest:

```
sudo apt-cache search nvidia
```

See what you get back.  I bet you can find a package to reinstall, like so:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common (*which may show up as "already installed")
```

If its already installed.  Then I recommend removing it and reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-common
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
sudo shutdown -r now
```

This will then reboot the pc.  If this does not work.  Try to download the source driver from Nvidia's site.  There you can also find the instructions to install the drivers from the drivers they offer for Linux.